# Game loop design

Tags: c++, game-loop, windows

I'm developing a simple Win game. Here is my 2 similar implementations of the game loop (in c++):

approach #1:

```
while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {

        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        else {
            // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff
        }
}
```

approach #2:

```
while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {

        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        
        // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff
        
}}
```

My question is which one is better and which one should i choose? Is it better to do the update and rendering stuff in the else closure as in the #1 approach or just in the `while` loop block as in the #2 approach?

Comment: This looks like a question for [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There's also a [similar, old question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/game-loop-on-windows) that OP may find helpful.