# Game loop c++ implementation

Tags: c++, game-loop

I'm starting to develop some simple 3D game. The basic topic for a start is the *game loop*.

There is a solution:

```
while (true) 
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE)
    {
        // Translate and dispatch message
    }

    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {
        break;
    }

   // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff

}
```

proposed by *Syntac_* in [this thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/game-loop-on-windows?newreg=93958a06152f46469ae4476592aa34b5).

The above answer revived positive feedback WHILE the solution seems to NOT be valid!
When I click on the close ('X') button (or just press ALt+F4) to close the main app window nothing happens - the app is still running! Fast investigation - the problem is that the app receives some extra *WM_TIMER* message after the *WM_QUIT* message so the  `if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)` is NEVER reached!

Comment: Did you mean to check for the quit message and quit the game inside the peek message loop, instead of outside of it? [This problem was already pointed out nine years ago in the thread you linked](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/game-loop-on-windows?newreg=93958a06152f46469ae4476592aa34b5#comment105805_59860)

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, that'd solve the problem BUT I'm wondering HOW this solution IS approved as valid since as I've told it isn't working!?

Comment: Having the most [up votes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) doesn't mean the solution is valid. Even an [accepted answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) isn't necessarily proof of correctness or validity.

Comment: It sounds like it works under some conditions which unfortunately are not universal. This is not unusual in software development. Here, folks were probably mainly upvoting the suggestion to use a while loop to check for messages, and the exact handling of quit was considered a minor detail a reader could sort out for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern for a Win32 game loop is:

```
MSG msg = {};
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        // Tick which is usually one or more Updates + 1 Render
    }
}
```

This ensures you will eventually see the `WM_QUIT` and exit the loop without any message order dependencies. It also makes sure you process all pending application messages *before* proceeding with the next frame Tick to keep it responsive.

Also make sure in your `WndProc` you do:

```
switch(message)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
...
```

and a helper like this is useful too for logic-based triggering of exit:

```
void ExitGame() noexcept
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
```

> I suspect another problem here is because you are making heavy use of `WM_TIMER` messages for your game timing, which is really easy to overload the system with requests. It's also 'wall clock' timing which isn't necessarily the right choice for your game timer.

> A better answer is do your own time event detection inside the game loop. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/understanding-game-time-revisited/) for details on using [StepTimer.h](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d11game_uwp/StepTimer.h).

See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) for an bunch of simple game loops plus Direct3D device & swapchain.

Answer (score 1):

There are other reasons why you might want to quit the game. For example when the player selects "quit to desktop" from the main menu. I would therefore recommend to add a flag variable `quitGame` and set that variable to true when you want to end the game for *any* reason. Then just check that variable in your while-loop:

```
bool quitGame = false;

while (!quitGame) 
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE)) 
    {
        // Translate and dispatch message
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            quitGame = true;
        }
    }

    // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff

}
```